# "MySQl server has gone away" error

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm running a Ruby multi-threaded application that collects data over the internet and then connects to MySQL to do a simple insert:

```
insert into churches.us values('','NULL','XYZ Christian Church','43.268158','-99.731361','0011111111111','200 N XYZ Ave','Shmack City','Shmack%2CCity','IA',NOW())
```

Everything works great until there are around 2600 records in the database. 
Then some (not all) of the attempts to insert end up in the error: "MySQL server has gone away". The query that fails looks normal and works if I run them manually. Also no slow queries are being logged to the file configured in my.cnf. No errors appear in mysql.err.

I can't figure out why I get the error.

There is plenty of memory on the server:

```
free -lmh 
total used free shared buffers cached 
Mem: 8.8G 1.1G 7.7G 6.4M 94M 162M 
Low: 8.8G 1.1G 7.7G 
High: 0B 0B 0B 
-/+ buffers/cache: 863M 7.9G 
Swap: 2.0G 0B 2.0G 


select count(*) from churches.us 

+----------+ 
| count(*) | 
+----------+ 
| 2527 | 
+----------+ 

root@fd001:~/test# mysql -u root -p'bleeeeep' -e "show variables like '%wait%';show variables like '%errors%'" 
+---------------------------------------------------+----------+ 
| Variable_name | Value | 
+---------------------------------------------------+----------+ 
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 3600 | 
| innodb_spin_wait_delay | 6 | 
| lock_wait_timeout | 31536000 | 
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size | 10000 | 
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_size | 10 | 
| wait_timeout | 28800 | 
+---------------------------------------------------+----------+ 
+--------------------+---------+ 
| Variable_name | Value | 
+--------------------+---------+ 
| max_connect_errors | 1000000 | 
| slave_skip_errors | OFF | 
+--------------------+---------+ 

root@fd001:~/test# mysql -u root -p'bleeep' -e "show status like '%conn%'; show status like '%thread%'" 
+--------------------------+-------+ 
| Variable_name | Value | 
+--------------------------+-------+ 
| Aborted_connects | 0 | 
| Connections | 3105 | 
| Max_used_connections | 25 | 
| Ssl_client_connects | 0 | 
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0 | 
| Ssl_finished_connects | 0 | 
| Threads_connected | 8 | 
+--------------------------+-------+ 
+------------------------------------------+-------+ 
| Variable_name | Value | 
+------------------------------------------+-------+ 
| Delayed_insert_threads | 0 | 
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost | 0 | 
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0 | 
| Slow_launch_threads | 0 | 
| Threads_cached | 8 | 
| Threads_connected | 8 | 
| Threads_created | 83 | 
| Threads_running | 2 | 
+------------------------------------------+-------+ 


key_buffer = 128M 
max_allowed_packet = 256M 
max_connect_errors = 1000000 
thread_stack = 192K 
thread_cache_size = 16 
max_connections = 1024 
table_cache = 256 
thread_concurrency = 1024 

root@fd001:~/test# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.13.0-40-generic (buildd@comet) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #69-        Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 13 17:53:56 UTC 2014 

root@fd001:~/test# ruby -v 
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Ruby problem at all, but more likely a network or MySQL configuration issue. I'd recommend searching on [su] or maybe [dba.se].

Comment: In my code I was trying to stick to best practices; Open connection , make all your inserts, then close connection. The problem disappear as soon as I changed that - opening connections immediately before insert and closing as soon as the insert is done. The program is now flying. Anyone knows why would that fist method be inefficient ?

Comment: It depends on how long it takes your code to become active after opening the connection. A lot of DBMs don't want open connections hanging around unless they're being used; It's costly. The timeout should be configurable.

Comment: The timeout is configurable and it's set ti 28800 seconds (8 hours). The program however was disconnecting in space of several minutes. the program was much slower than expected. I will post the code alter on.